# Single buffer line from 74ABT244 to 16 inputs for 74AHC245?

Tags: driver, buffer

I am designing a circuit which will buffer 3.3V input from Raspberry pi using 74ABT244D,623 and there will be 4 output chains on the PCB. Each chain will be connected through FRC to a second PCB with an immediate buffer of 74AHC245. But one data line will be shorted into 4 to get 4 outputs.

So from 1 single output of 74ABT244D,623, can it drive 4 inputs to 4 74AHC245 each (16 total) ?

Reference image :-
[image]

Comment: The answer might depend on what FRC is.

Answer (score 0):

What does your datasheet say?

-32mA (hi) 64 mA (Lo) drive

+/-1 uA load + 10pf (Ic=C dV/dt) per transition

What is load capacitance? And frequency? To determine Zc

So far so good, what f ? low? No problem

- make sure to use decoupling cap on IC’s.  ~0.01 uF typ.

Comment: I don't understand this - So far so good, what f ? low? No problem

Comment: Sorry but can you explain again

Comment: @Sap what is your frequency, at DC it can drive 32,000 gates"? I mean on this output

Comment: 32 Mhz maximum. 19.2 Mhz typical

Comment: Not uC, I meant on this bus, CMOS takes very little current on input, you are OK there (so far, OK, what is your load? mA or type or,

Comment: You can drive 3 LEDS in parallel from each output to 3.3V (white). 0.3V/ (25~50)ohms= <12 total mA or from (5V -3.0V)/ 25~50)= 40 to 80 mA total /3LEDs = 13 mA to 27 mA per LED unless you add resistors or CC regulator, but 80 mA is too much for Driver output so you must tell us what you are driving,!!